# Terminology: subsequence, rearranged subsequence, etc.

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, terminology

Suppose I have two sequences, $A=(a_i)_{i\ge 0}$ and $B=(b_i)_{i\ge 0}$. (The restriction to infinite sequences is not essential, I could ask the same question about finite sequences.)

If there are indices $0 \le n_0 < n_1 < \ldots$ such that $a_i = b_{n_i}$ for all $i\ge0$ then $A$ is called a subsequence of $B$.

If the ordering of indices is dropped so that I only require $n_i \ne n_j$ for $i \ne j$, is there a name for the relationship of $A$ to $B$? (If you sort $A$, the result is a subsequence of $B$.)

If even that restriction is dropped, is there a name for the relationship of $A$ to $B$? (If you sort $A$ and drop the duplicates, the result is a subsequence of $B$.)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $a_i=b_{n_i}$? That seems to be the more "standard" definition of a subsequence. What you described is more a "have some elements in common" relationship.

Comment: @Ingix Thanks for the correction.